# Invalidating Cached Data and Dependency Injection Pattern

Tags: asp.net-core, dependency-injection, .net-core, simple-injector

I have a data cache class (that uses the `MemoryCache` class).

The basic function of this class is to cache reference data.  To get this reference data it needs an instance of an Entity Framework dbContext.  This gets passed in by dependency injection (Simple Injector).

But this dbContext has a lifecycle of "per call" (`AsyncScopedLifestyle`).  So to satisify this I put the call to setup the cache in a "scope" that expires after the call.

The cache gets invalidated every 2 hours and is re-queried.  Unsurprisingly, the dbContext has been cleaned up by then (because it went out of the scope).

I can think of ways to get around this issue.  But I want to know if there is a pattern I should be following for this kind of issue.  (Most of my solutions have me passing the container into my cache class.  But that seems to be a violation of several DI patterns.)

**Anyone know of a design pattern to use when you have a reoccurring need for an injection inside of a class?**

A bit more background:

- My cache class (called `DataCache`) gets the context from constructor injection.
- The call to set it up is made from the Configure method in Startup.cs.  This looks like this:

.

```
using (AsyncScopedLifestyle.BeginScope(container))
{
    // Setup the long lived data caching
    var dataCache = container.GetInstance<DataCache>();
    dataCache.SetupCachedItems();
}
```

- It sets the MemoryCache to expire the data in the cache after two hours.  But the injected context is long cleaned up by then.

Comment: What does the data cache class look like? Where does it get the context from and how? In any case, it should request a context only when it needs to load new data. When that happens, it needs to create a scope to get that per-call context.

Comment: Check [Consuming a scoped service in a background task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio#consuming-a-scoped-service-in-a-background-task). The problem is similar.

Comment: Can you not use a `BackgroundService` that is set up via `AddHostedService` that runs in the background periodically refreshing the cache? The DBContext could be injected into the `BackgroundService` and thus be available outside the scope of an individual request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two general solutions here:

1. Move the cache that the `DataCache` manages out of that class, in such way that `MyCacheClass` can become `Scoped`. This seams a no-brainer as this is likely what `MemoryCache` is for. Memory cache is likely a Singleton.
2. Move `DataCache` into the [Composition Root](https://mng.bz/K1qZ) so it can safely depend on the container (or a container abstraction), without falling into [Service Locator anti-pattern](https://mng.bz/WaQw) trap.

The first solution can be applied in multiple ways. Perhaps it's a matter of defining the cache in a `static` field:

```cs
public class DataCache
{
    private static ConcurrentDictionary<string, object> cache;
}
```

And in case you inject `MemoryCache` as storage provider for your data, it will contain the cache, and the lifestyle of `DataCache` becomes irrelevant:

```cs
public class DataCache
{
    public DataCache(MyContext context, IMemoryCache cache)
}
```

If, however, `DataCache` needs to be injected into Singleton consumers, it itself needs to be Singleton. This disallows this approach, as `MyContext` needs to be Scoped, to prevent [Captive Dependencies](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/02/captive-dependency/). For that you can use solution 2.

With solution to, you ensure that `DataCache` is created inside your [Composition Root](https://mng.bz/K1qZ). This forces you to hide `DataCache` behind an abstraction, e.g. `IDataCache`. This abstraction can be placed in a location that allows consumers to depend on, while the `DataCache` implementation will be completely hidden inside the Composition Root. At that location it becomes safe to depend on the DI Container.

```cs
// Part of the Composition Root
sealed class DataCache: IDataCache
{
    public DataCache(Container container, IMemoryCache cache) ...

    public ProductData GetProductByKey(string key)
    {
        if (key not in cache)
        {
            using (AsyncScopedLifestyle.BeginScope(this.container))
            {
                var context = container.GetInstance<MyContext>();
                var p = context.Products.SingleOrDefault(p => p.Key == key);
                var data = new ProductData(p);
                AddProductToCache(key, data);
                return data;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked well (Option 2).  The key part I was missing was the "Composition Root" concept.  I felt like I was doing it wrong to pass the container into my DataCache.  But I abstracted DataCache behind an interface (IDataCache) for the rest of the application and it seems clean.  Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

You should rely on DI the whole way. In other words, if the cache class needs the context, then that's a dependency, and should be injected as such:

```
public class MyCacheClass
{
    private readonly MyContext _context;

    public MyCacheClass(MyContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    ...
}
```

That of course assumes the cache class has a scoped lifetime as well, which there's really no reason it shouldn't, since it interacts with scoped dependencies. However, if for some reason you need it to have a singleton lifetime, then you can simply inject `IServiceProvider` and then create a scope and pull out the context when you need it:

```
using (var scope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope())
{
    var context = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<MyContext>();
    // do something with context
}
```

If you're using a static class, don't.

Comment: Sorry to downvote you although the answer is nicely written. I really don't like the (ab)use of the service locator here. Service locator is anti pattern because there is always a better solution. And although asp.net core is tagged the question is not really related to IServiceProvider.

Comment: That's not what the down vote is for. And, when you have a Singleton class, that's your only option. There is no better alternative. As I said in my answer, it would be better to use a scoped lifetime.

Comment: Also it is, because regardless of what DI container you use, it still uses the Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection facades.

Comment: My cache runs in a singleton lifetime.  Because it just hangs around trying to prevent slower calls.  If it gets re-created for each scope instance (ie each call), then there would be no point in having the cache.  But the context it uses (to get the reference data) is scoped for each call, because that is its primary use.  Maybe I should make a separate EF Core dbContext that is use used for calls to get the cache data?  And make that one have a singleton scope too?

Comment: Ric is referring to is the [Service Locator (SL) anti-pattern](https://mng.bz/WaQw), and SL is a bad idea. It's important to note, however, that whether or not this code example is an implementation of SL, depends on *where* `MyCacheClass` is declared. Depending on `IServiceProvider` is fine, long as `MyCacheClass` is part of the [Composition Root](https://mng.bz/K1qZ). My main criticism to Chris’ answer is that it lacks the warning that `MyCacheClass` must become part of the Composition Root.

Comment: "Also it is, because regardless of what DI container you use, it still uses the Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection facades." This comment is incorrect, because this assumes that all DI Containers have an adapter on top of the MS.DI abstractions. This, however, is not the case as both Simple Injector and Castle Windsor *do not* have such adapter. Your last example that creates an `IServiceScope` and resolves the `MyContext` will utterly break when applied to Simple Injector.

Comment: I tried this out and it gave me this error: `SimpleInjector.ActivationException: 'No registration for type IServiceProvider could be found.` when I tried to get an IServiceProvider from the Dependency Injection class.

Comment: The cache is injected into the class (`IMemoryCache`). As such, the cache persists past the life of this class. All this is is a convenience class that wraps around the cache, and such can be totally transient. You only need to have a singleton lifetime if the the class *itself* is persisting some sort of state. Here it's delegating persistence to something that is long lived, so it doesn't need to be.